# vb.net web browser control javascript and php

Tags: vb.net

I am new to VB.NET. I created a simple web browser with refresh, back, and go buttons and the web browser control. Now my problem is whenever I load a site with javascript there's an error message that pops up. What I want is to automatically enable javascript on the web browser control. Furthermore, whenever I load a php site it takes too long to load. Pls help me. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the `ScriptErrorsSuppressed` property of the WebBrowser to `True`? That should prevent the dialogs from appearing.